# sending value of model property as an ajax parameter

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jsonresult

I have following form in my view-page

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product_ID)

   <input id="idd" type="file" class="file">

   // form sumbit button
   <input type = "submit" value="Create" /> 

}
```

I want to send above inserted `Product_ID` as ajax object route value before click the submit button of this form.for that I created it like this `product_ID = Model.Product_ID` but this `product_ID` getting null.

```
$('#idd').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateDirectory", "Home",new { product_ID = Model.Product_ID })',
        type: "POST",
```

controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateDirectory(string product_ID)
    {
      ...........
    }
```

**EDIT**

using alert inside above script I try to show that Product_ID

`alert('@Model.Product_ID');`

same results not showing value

Comment: there is a `data` parameter, used to POST data.

Comment: can I use like this  `<input id="idd" type="file" class="file" data="@Model.Product_ID">` and in ajax call  `data: data-Product_ID,` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Url.Action()` is razor code which is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view so if the initial value of `Model.Product_ID` is `null` then your code will render just `url: '/Home/CreateDirectory'`. Changing the value in the textbox once it has been generated will not update the value of url.

Instead use the ajax `data` option to pass the value of the textbox

```js
$('#idd').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateDirectory", "Home")', // modify
        data: { product_ID: $('#Product_ID').val() }, // add this
        type: "POST",
```

Comment: once I add your solution, and click that function  I'm getting following popup window http://i.imgur.com/fa7lX8I.jpg ,

Comment: this is the ajax code I used is there any problem in that https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/epGKr

Comment: First you need to remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` (your not sending json). Second, the alert is just displaying what your controller sends back i.e. the value of `response.responseText` so there is obviously an issue with the code in your `CreateDirectory()` method

Comment: Actually, because of the `contentType` option, it would be throwing a `500 (Internal Server Error)` and your just seeing the results of that error.

Comment: I put debug point in controller method, but once I click its not directing to this method, also I try to print the productID using alert [like this new edit of ajax](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/epGKr) . this is my [controller method](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/GGozb) and Its worked fine earlier

Comment: I cannot even see an element with `id="idd"` in your revised code

Comment: I want to get this value before I sumbit this form , is this possible to do here the whole code https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/apGK7

Comment: I don't understand what your doing. Why are you running this code when you click on the file input control? Do you mean you want it to run when you click on the submit button?

Comment: Actually here is the scenario 1 .I have a form 2. I can I insert product_ID and rest of the fields of this form, bottom of this form I have file input (browse button-to upload files that relevant to this product) , 3. then I click browse files button Its generating the folder in a specific location of my project ,  then 4. Once I click sumbit button I can sumbit this form and upload those files

Comment: click browse files button Its generating the folder , this folder name is the product ID which is I inserted initially of this form

Comment: You want to keep generating the same folder every time a user clicks on the file input? Just create the folder when you submit the form (and check first if it already exists). Your just degrading the performance of your app

Comment: nope Once I click browse files button(which is located at bottom of this form) its generating folder , its name is product ID which I previously inserted , did you get my idea, pls let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95984/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kez).

Answer (score 2):

In this line you are giving to product_ID the initial value in which the model is render in page, so it is probably null

```
url: '@Url.Action("CreateDirectory", "Home",new { product_ID = Model.Product_ID })'
```

try this instead

```
url: '@Url.Action("CreateDirectory", "Home")' + '?product_ID=' + $("Product_ID").val()
```

**EDIT**
Maybe you need this too

```
 [HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateDirectory([FromUri]string product_ID)
{
  ...........
}
```

Comment: this is wrong answer, mvc action has attribute HttpPost, and then do not accept get parameters

Comment: So do this  `[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateDirectory([FromUri]string product_ID)
    {
      ...........
    }`
And an HttpPost can receive parameters from uri

Comment: If still not getting the value can you tell me what is going on the request? and the full uri of the request?

Answer (score 2):

its because your action accept only [HttpPost] data
and you are sending variable in query string [HttpGet]

```
@Url.Action("CreateDirectory", "Home",new { product_ID = Model.Product_ID })
```

url is next:

```
~/Home/CreateDirectory?product_ID = ....
```

Replace [HttpPost] attribute with [HttpGet], or just remove it

and set ajax {type: "GET"}

Alternatively:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateDirectory", "Home")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { product_ID: '@(Model.Product_ID)' }
```

Or:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateDirectory", "Home")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { product_ID: $('#Product_ID').val() }
```

Comment: An HttpPost can still receive parameters by uri

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine.

```
@model ProductInfoVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product_ID)

}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<input id="idd" type="file" class="file">

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $('#idd').click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {productID = @Model.Product_ID})',
                type: "POST"
            });
        });

    })

</script>
```

Assuming you have an HttpPost action method which accepts the `productID`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string productId)
{
   // to do : do something
}
```

The only reason i can think of as the reason of NULL coming is, Your Model.`Product_ID` itself is NULL when you render the page. So i would look into your GET action method to see whether you are properly setting the `Product_ID` property value of your view model.

Comment: `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>` do I need add this in view page also , because I added this line in Layout then I refer that layout in tp of viewpage `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")`

Comment: If you have that in the layout , you don't need to add that in the page.

Comment: I used the above code and it worked fine. You might have some other code which is breaking this behavior. Copy the code in above answer and try( just this code)

Comment: tried to print the product Id , that I insered like this    `$('#idd').click(function () { alert('@Model.Product_ID');....`  Im getting null